# Add a server to haproxy with initial state

Tags: haproxy

Whenever I update my haproxy configuration to add a node, haproxy adds it in the UP state by default. With the next health check, it is marked as down.

Is there a way to add a node in the DOWN or MAINT state initially?

Comment: It seems that 7 years later there is still no solution to this, to make the default state DOWN and to not sending requests to servers in the initial state (until HaProxy health-check will discover, that this server should be marked as DOWN)..

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the health check settings using this (for exemple):

- option httpchk HEAD /alive.html

It's a simple html file (in the default vhost for apache if you use apache) using by haproxy for checking the health of a node.
If you want to set a node at the down state when you add it, just move out this file.

Comment: Yes, but it will mark it down at the first health check only. Not at the initial state. There could be 1-2 secs after with it will appear down on haproxy @Jeremy